# Animating 2 items independently without stuttering/pausing

Tags: wpf, animation

I'm trying to understand how I can perform the following animation operation with WPF without the top section of my animation pausing if the bottom section is performing an animation In around the same timeframe.

```
|--------------------------------------------|
|    A   |    B   |    C   |    D   |    E   | <---- Animates each Cell left from (offscreen) F, G, H 
|--------------------------------------------|       etc looping back to A
|                                            |
|                                            |
|             main area (animations)         |
|                                            |
|                                            |
----------------------------------------------
```

I have my screen setup with a grid and the following 2 usercontrols.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height=".25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="102" Name="imageRow"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Name="displayRow">
        <my:ScrollElementsControl x:Name="OrderScroll" />
    </Grid>

    <an:PageTransition Name="pageTransitionControl" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" TransitionType="FlipAndFade" ClipToBounds="true">

    </an:PageTransition>

</Grid>
```

the ScrollElements control is a canvas, that looks after it's own animation storyboard, but if the 2 animations seem to fall into Close sync then the Canvas animation is stops/stutters whilst the MainArea animation performs.

How can I ensure that the top animation continues to animate when the bottom animation animates (but on a different cycle)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ideal WPF world, jerky animations are not issue of multiple ones running at same time. But sadly they do cause stuttering. Try to use the animations as part of the SAME story board. Single parent story board manages smooth transitions between multiple running animations as per my knowledge...

Comment: i was worried i'd find this as the answer. I have made my usercontrols with their own storyboards so that they could be reused. I guess given the time is up on working on this part I'll have to wait until the next iteration of the project to see if i can refactor to 1 storyboard for the system instead of for each control.

Comment: @Paul, do keep us posted when you fix this.